# ImageJ calculating area of solid

Tags: imagej

I have a series of images of Ice that I want to analyse to determine the area of solid versus liquid. An example image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0Ren.jpg). This is similar to a porosity measurement however Im struggling as the colours are too similar to simply do Threshold.

At the moment I'm having to play around with the contrast/find edges/despeckle/make binary to make the crystals easier to identify.

I then pass them through morphological segmentation:
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIYt5.jpg) and then threshold to work out area.

Is there an easier way to do this to work out the area of ice versus the area of space/liquid without having to trace out each crystal?

Answer (score 0):

Your image has an uneven background illumination, so it makes sense to do a background subtraction. And Find Edges is a nice preprocessing step to enhance the edges to make the Morphological Segmentation (a reasonable tool here) easier.

Here is a sample macro which automates many of these steps:

```js
// Perform a background subtraction.
orig = getImageID();
run("Duplicate...", " ");
dupl = getImageID();
run("Gaussian Blur...", "sigma=50");
imageCalculator("Subtract create 32-bit", orig, dupl);

// Enhance the edges.
run("Find Edges");

// Run Morphological Segmentation.
run("Morphological Segmentation");
wait(1000); // HACK
call("inra.ijpb.plugins.MorphologicalSegmentation.segment", "tolerance=20", "calculateDams=true", "connectivity=6");
call("inra.ijpb.plugins.MorphologicalSegmentation.setDisplayFormat", "Catchment basins");
call("inra.ijpb.plugins.MorphologicalSegmentation.createResultImage");
```

The resulting image has each region with a different solid value:

[image: segmented ice]

From there you could create a histogram (*Analyze > Histogram*) to get the count of each intensity value—i.e., the area of each object. For some strange reason it didn't work for me until I duplicated the result image first (<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>).

[image: histogram]

You can click the Copy button to put the entire histogram into the clipboard, and then paste it into a spreadsheet program or text file, for analysis in other tools.

There are surely other (and probably better) ways to analyze the Catchment basins "labeling" image from Morphological Segmentation; consider asking on the [ImageJ Forum](http://forum.imagej.net/) for more ideas and suggestions.

Another simpler option you could try is the [Trainable Weka Segmentation](https://imagej.net/TWS).